# Geoserver Long Startup Time

Tags: geoserver

I had pre-configured Geoserver and can successfully start it up but only on odd occasions it takes a very long time to initialise gws-gs.xml. It can take over 30 minutes before it initialises gwc-gs.xml and just hangs. Therefore, I tried to configure everything else but gwc-gs.xml and found a /gewc/rest/reload api call that also failed because of a known bug in version 12.15 that I am using. However, I have also read on forums that gwc reload api call is known to have no effect even after being called successfully. I will be very grateful if someone who has experienced similar issues can advise.